# Change date format [YYYYMMDD] to [MM/DD/YYYY]

Tags: google-sheets, formulas, google-sheets-dates

I generated a report that formats date as 20160509 and my Google Sheets locale is already set to United States. I've played around with various options within Format > Number > Date Format but I can't change the dates to MM/DD/YYYY format without doing a simple find and replace. How do I accomplish this?

[image]

Comment: The problem is really that Sheets isn't recognizing that as a date. I don't think you can simply format that into a date format you like; you'll need a "helper" column to transform the string into a date format Sheets recognizes.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Assuming your string is in cell A1, this formula will convert it to a date. You can then format the date however you prefer.

```
=date(left(A1,4),mid(A1,5,2),right(A1,2))
```

Or, take the leftmost four characters as the year, the rightmost two characters as the day, and two characters in the middle starting at position 5 as the month, and convert it to a date.

```
19961210
```

turns into

```
12/10/1996
```

(standard American date format)

---

From Google Support:

- [date(year,month,day)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3092969)
- [left(string,character count)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094079)
- [mid(string,start,count)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094129)
- [right(string,character count)](https://support.google.com/docs/answer/3094087)

Answer (score 5):

If you want a proper date (recommended) please try:

```
=date(left(C2,4),mid(C2,5,2),right(C2,2))
```

Custom Format as Number `mm/dd/yyyy` to show leading `0`s.

If you want a text string to include leading `0`s please try:

```
=mid(C2,5,2)&"/"&right(C2,2)&"/"&left(C2,4)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is what I use in my helper column using the inbuilt google sheets function:

`=text(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(A1)),"MM/DD/YYYY")`

This is also what I use when I need put a date string as the part of a filename:

The function `datevalue()` accepts any date string format including the excel raw date numbers that you have on your 1st column. `TO_DATE()` converts the `datevalue()` to something lawyers can read. The outer function `Text(,"")` allows you to modify the date format.

I use it to return integers that can be used in formulas dealing with dates on google sheets.

The how:
Those raw numbers on your 1st column? 1 is January 1st 1900.  2 is January 2, 1900 ..and so on...

In google sheets, each cell on your column is equal to the number of days after December 30, 1899, [post-gilded age, when the U.S. became a corporate state under admiralty law and issues public policies instead of common law, meaning no one is supposed to harm you unless you agree to waiving your rights].

The function `to_date()`converts that raw date value to a format more recognizable.
The function is equivalent to clicking on the taskbar `Format` > `Number` > `Date` > `time` from the menu bar.

As a side note:
The function `=Text(TO_DATE(DATEVALUE(A1)),"MM-DD-YYYY)"` in a helper column is what I use to convert any date string into a string format usable for windows file names since `/` is not accepted for windows file naming. No need to worry if the date has a missing leading zero.

Comment: This answer was marked as low quality. Please consider to add a brief explanation about how this formula answers the question.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the formula for the one of you trying to convert a date were the 0 would have been removed:

`=date(right(J5,4),if(mid(J5,2,1) = "/",left(J5,1),left(J5,2)),if(mid(J5,3,1) = "/",mid(J5,4,if(mid(J5,5,1) ="/",1,2)),if(mid(J5,2,1) = "/",mid(J5,3,if(mid(J5,5,1) = "/",2,1)))))`

In this case I'm going from American to European:
M/d/yyyy, MM/d/yyyy, MM/dd/yyyy or M/dd/yyyy and convert it to dd/MM/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

You can set your sheet location in sheet settings (*File* → *Sheet settings*). Your sheet will show you the right format for you.

Answer (score -3):

Click the gear icon on the right from your main Google Drive dashboard and select Settings. If you don't have a language selected you can set it here. This should apply to all future documents.

[image]

Either you can change the default calendar setting for google doc as follows:

Under

> File > Spreadsheet settings > Change locale or Timezone

Comment: Thanks for helping but I generated a report that formats date as 20160509 and my Google Sheets locale is already set to United States.

Comment: Follow the following menu list: Format > Number > More Format(at bottom) > More date and time format.  Now you can add delete each thing separately. Hope it helps.

Comment: Yep, tired that too and keep on getting unexpected output :/